# Phone Number not clickable using Azure Bot Framework Web Chat

Tags: html, azure, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker, tel

### Setup

I created a Azure QnA Web Chat Bot using [QnAMaker](https://www.qnamaker.ai/), [Azure Bot Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/bot-service/#overview), and the [Bot Framework Web Chat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/README.md) client in JavaScript.

Here's an example of how I'm initializing the bot with HTML + JS:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/4.6.0/webchat-es5.js"></script>

<div id="projekt-webchat" role="main"></div>
```

```js
window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
    {
       directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
          secret: 'SECRETHERE'
       }),
       userID: 'YOUR_USER_ID',
       username: 'Web Chat User',
       locale: 'en-US',
       botAvatarInitials: 'WC',
       userAvatarInitials: 'WW'
    },
    document.getElementById('projekt-webchat')
);
```

My bot is connected to a KnowledgeBase from QnA Maker which has a **QnA Pair** like this:

**Question**: `gimmenumber`
**Answer**: `+49 5251 123456`

### Native Browser Detection

Some browsers will render this as a clickable hyperlink and Ichoose to call that number.  However, others browsers do not see the phone number as a hyperlink, so I can't click on it

- **Works** - Microsoft Edge 41
- **Works** - Microsoft EdgeHTML 16
- **Broken** - Google Chrome Version 78
- **Broken** - Microsoft Edge Version 79

I've tried to change my answer from `+49 5251 123456` to the following:

- `<a href="tel:123-456-7890">123-456-7890</a>`
- `<a rel="nofollow" class="external free" href="tel:+49-30-1234567">tel:+49-30-1234567</a>`.

But the answer just looks like as those tags `<a></a>` are no tags but normal text. (So still not clickable and it looks ugly).

Just out of curiosity I created this HTML by itself which has the same situation for all the browsers above:

```
<div>+49 5251 123456</div>
```

Why is this happening? Can I fix it? How can I fix it so the phone numbers are clickable?

### Markdown Rendering

The bot service will also render markdown in answers to format text as bold, italics, or links.

So the following examples work

```cs
//making headings works with this
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("# " + turnContext.Activity.From.Id));
//bold works
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("**" + turnContext.Activity.From.Id + "**"));
```

However, when I try to render telephone numbers using markdown, I still run into issues.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```cs
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("[example](tel:123456)"));
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("[example](tel:+49 5251 123456)"));
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("[example](tel:+495251123456)"));
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("[example](tel:05251123456)"));
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("[example](tel:05251 123456)"));
```

Which ends up rendering incorrectly like this:

[image: Example Chatbot Output with tel not working]

Comment: You need to use an anchor with `tel:{number here}` as the href - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: @Pete https://imgur.com/a/d9S6g9j did not work sadly :(

Comment: works fine for me in chrome and edge: https://jsfiddle.net/ryan4wtu/ - do you have anything that can make the calls on the device you are testing it on - if not the obviously nothing will happen

Comment: I assume it has something to do with the Azure WebChat Bot itself. In qnamaker.ai and the web chat window the message looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/IwVwNz3 - Another thing I noticed is that I can use markdown format in qnamaker.ai like this `[example](tel:12345)`. But in the webchat window I only see "example" which is not clickable.

Comment: Another thing I noticed: If I write something like this ´**myText**´ myText will be bold in the webchat window. Is there anything other than markdown where text goes bold if between those ´** **´?

Comment: So it sounds like you narrowed down the problem to an HTML / browser issue, and the chatbot/azure context is not relevant? If so, can you simplify the question?

Comment: Here's the officially supported [markdown format reference from QnA Maker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/reference-markdown-format).  Links should definitely work, but it doesn't seem to process non https? URIs

Comment: You have created the following html `<div>+49 5251 123456</div>`. Can you also add a click event/ class on that HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably show the phone number in seperate elements. When the elements are displayed as an inline block, the webbrowser will not create a hyperlink.

Comment: I have created an example .html only with this in it `<div>+49 5251 161920</div>`. The number is clickable with Microsoft Edge 41.16299.611.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299 but not in the other 2 browsers. Do I have to activly deactivate the inline block for the 2 browsers somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to achieve `<div>+49 5251 123456</div>`. Can you try adding an `onclick` event and some CSS like the code snippet below?

```
<div onclick="window.open('tel:+49 5251 123456', '_self');" style='cursor:pointer'>+49 5251 123456</div>
```