# Phone Number not clickable in Bot-WebChat window with some Browsers

Tags: azure, chatbot, phone-number, azure-qna-maker

My question got closed because the question has been answered already.

My question is here: [Phone Number not clickable in some Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59196143/phone-number-not-clickable-in-some-browsers)

What has been solved now is that my HTML now has a clickable phone number:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><a href="tel:+49 5251 123456">+49 5251 123456</a></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the main problem I had isn't solved yet. In one of the three browsers the phone number is clickable in the chat window but I want it to work for every browser.

I tried to change my `answer` from `+49 5251 123456` to `<a href="tel:+49 5251 123456">+49 5251 123456</a>` but in the chat window it looks like this (very first line) https://i.stack.imgur.com/aomzX.jpg

I got an answer in my comments too. But it didn't work for the webchat window.

Answer in Comment was: `You need to use an anchor with tel:{number here} as the href - developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a`

*edit*

I can use markdown format in my answer of the QnA Pair `~~striketrough~~` actually strikes out `striketrough` **in qnamaker.ai**. Maybe it is possible to make the phone number clickable with markdown?

*edit2*

I though I almost had it. I tried `[phone](tel:+49 5251 123456)` this makes the phone number actually clickable... in qnamaker.ai only :(

I tried it in the web chat window of the bot and sadly the bot only answers with `example` and `striketrough`.`example` is not clickable and `striketrough` is not striked out.

*edit3*

I feel like the phone numbers should actually be clickable. Maybe something is wrong with the browsers or internally with the azure web chat?

a few examples I have done:

```
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("[example](tel:123456)"));
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("[example](tel:+49 5251 123456)"));
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("[example](tel:+495251123456)"));
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("[example](tel:05251123456)"));
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("[example](tel:05251 123456)"));
```

ends up looking like this:

[image]

Comment: *Which browsers* are the issue?  Please be specific

Comment: @gravity First Browser is the Microsoft Edge Browser: Microsoft Edge 41.16299.611.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299 The second Browser is Google Chrome: Google Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-Bit) and the third Browser is a Mircosoft Edge Browser but a beta version: Microsoft Edge Version 79.0.309.40 (Official build) beta (64-bit)

Comment: Looks like your original question ([Phone Number not clickable in some Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59196143/phone-number-not-clickable-in-some-browsers)) is re-opened, so it'd be good to consolidate research efforts there